# Translate partials with i18n from shared folder in a Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-i18n

I am new using i18n in Rails, I am struggling to figure out how to translate a partial from the shared folder in another view.

I am using lazy loading in my **application.rb** file

```
    config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('config', 'locales', '**', '*.{rb,yml}')]
```

My **app/views** folder looks like this:
[image: app/views]

My **config/locales** folder looks like this:
[image]

My **config/locales/views/pages/home.en.yml** looks like this:

```
en:
  pages:
    home:
      subtitle_1: "Get the profitability ratios of your real estate investment project."
```

The translation is working on my **pages/home.html.erb** when I call `<%= t('.subtitle_1') %>`

My **config/locals/views/shared/_footer.en.yml** looks like this:

```
en:
  shared:
    _footer:
      copyright_disclaimer: "xxx"
```

However, the translation is not working on my **pages/home.html.erb** when I render the partial **shared/_footer.html.erb** with `<%= t('copyright_disclaimer') %>`, it gets me a Copyright Disclaimer on my page instead of xxx.

My guess is that it is just a question of naming file, or yml lines, but I can't figure out what is the error after several attempts and research.

Thank you in advance for your help,

Have a great day,
Mth0158

Comment: Refering to this: https://webuild.envato.com/blog/how-to-organise-i18n-without-losing-your-translation-not-found/ ; I was able to make it work for a partial that is in the same "controller-related" folder, e.g. a partial **app/views/pages/_test.html.erb** with its associated yml file **config/locales/views/pages/_test.en.yml** can call its own yml file when displayed on **app/views/pages/home.html.erb** , it seems that it is not possible to do that from a different folder though... any clue?

Answer (score 0):

**ANSWER EDIT:**
From my understanding, if you use

```
config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('config', 'locales', '**', '*.{rb,yml}')]
```

Rails will parse the whole directory structure you have made and will concatenate these files for itself into big yml file per language. Then, when calling i18n on a view, Rails will retrieve the yml value based on your view path, e.g. for **app/views/pages/home.html.erb** it will by default retrieve `en/pages/home` keys.

If you want Rails to look into another place, you will have to specify the whole way, here I had to use `<%= t('shared._footer.copyright_disclaimer') %>` in my **app/views/shared/_footer.html.erb** so it can be displayed in any page with its correct translations.